# Is it possible to add Post Build Tasks/Steps to a Visual Studio website project?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2005, post-build-event, vs-web-site-project

I've got this ASP.NET 2.0 website project in Visual Studio that I've been working on for a while now. Over time the project grew little by little and in the end I ended up with quite a few steps that I had to run at the end, every time I wanted to publish the project.

So, I wrote a script that I can run which executes all the clean-up steps for me and which is pretty reliable.

Now, I was very dissatisfied to find that Visual Studio 2005 doesn't provide any means to execute post build tasks with website projects. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to [convert to a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5).

Comment: This seems to be what I needed.  I never realized there was a difference until now!

Answer (score 0):

The other solution would be to create a web deployment project for your website and add a MSBUILD task in its project file.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, but this is not what I was looking for.